# cakePHP: having model named 'Page'

Tags: cakephp, model, conflict

I'm going to create models named 'Book' and 'Page' which are related. How can I avoid conflicts between my 'Pages' and built-in 'Pages' of cakePHP inside View folder?

I should notice that I need built-in Pages of cakePHP to display some static pages such as contact us

Comment: The `View` subfolders are named according to the controller names, not the model, so there will be no conflict unless you have 2 controller named `PagesController` which is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just rename the default `PagesController` to something else like `StaticPagesController` (and related changes to routes and view folder). Then make a new `PagesController` & `Page` model.

You can even the existing `PagesController` if you wanted to by removing `public $uses = array();` from it. But since your book pages and static page rendering are unrelated it's best not to do so.